# Invoke Drop event from code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to invoke DragDrop event from code in winforms.

```
var ctrls = this.Owner.Controls.Find("mediaPlayer", true);
ctrls[0].??DragDrop(x,y)??
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why not setting the location ctrls.Location = new Point(x, y);

Comment: What stops you from doing it? What is the problem you face?

Comment: I need to drop programmaticaly to Control DataFormats.FileDrop. Control not my, but it handle Drag&Drop operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctrls = parentForm.Controls.Find("mediaPlayer", true);
Type t = typeof(Panel);
object[] p = new object[1];
p[0] = new DragEventArgs(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, new string[] {@"d:\test\test.avi"}), 0, 0,0, DragDropEffects.Copy, DragDropEffects.Copy);
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("OnDragDrop", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
m.Invoke(ctrls[0], p);
```

see [source](http://forums.asp.net/post/1471764.aspx)